# How to get value from module in another module - Terraform (Azure)

Tags: azure, terraform

Im trying to get value from one module and use it in another module.

I have module - **vnet**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.vnet_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  address_space       = var.address_space
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = "${var.vnet_name}-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = var.subnet_prefixes
}
```

and the **output** is :

```
output "subnet_id" {
    value = "${azurerm_subnet.subnet.id}"
}

output "vnet_name" {
    value = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
}
```

from this module i would like to get the vnet name and the subnet id for my other module that im using to create a nic.

**nic module**

```
module "vnet" {
  source = "../vnet" 
}


resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                = "${module.vnet.vnet_name}-nic"
  location            = "east us 2"
  resource_group_name = "null"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = " "
    subnet_id                     = module.vnet.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}
```

this way is working BUT the terraform plan , planning to create 2 resource per each resource because the way im using to get the values .

under nic module im using again the vnet module so its will create second vnet.

my **main.tf** is

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group.name
  location = var.resource_group.location
}

module "ib151w-vnet" {
  source              = "./modules/vnet"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    vnet_name = "ib151w-vnet"
    address_space       = var.address_space
    subnet_prefixes     = var.subnet_prefixes
}

module "ib151w-nic" {
  source              = "./modules/nic"
  name                = "nic-test-123"
  location            = "east us 2"
  resource_group_name = "ib151w"
}
```

the question is how can i get the vnet name and subnet id to use inside the nic module ?

> i know there is alot of better ways to establish my request but im
> just learning terraform and trying this specific way :)

Answer (score 1):

> how can i get the vnet name and subnet id to use inside the nic module

You have to **explicitly pass** those values in the root module:

```
module "ib151w-nic" {
  source              = "./modules/nic"
  name                = "nic-test-123"
  location            = "east us 2"
  resource_group_name = "ib151w"

  vnet_name             = module.vnet.vnet_name
  subnet_id             = module.vnet.subnet_id
}
```

Also you have to modify your `vnet` module to make vnets and subents **conditional**. For example, add variable in the `vent` module:

```
variable "should_create_vnet_and_subnet" {
    default = true
}
```

then make the resource conditional:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {

  count = should_create_vnet_and_subnet == true ? 1 : 0

  name                = var.vnet_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  address_space       = var.address_space
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {

  count = should_create_vnet_and_subnet == true ? 1 : 0

  name                 = "${var.vnet_name}-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = var.subnet_prefixes
}
```

And the rest. Basically you have to **rewrite your entire** `vnet` module around conditional resources.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things to reconsider here but I would like to stick to your query only as you have requested.

**How to get value from the module in another module - Terraform**

As I can see you are already using two modules for `vnet`(which includes subnet) and `nic` and also using two modules interface calls to use them. You can simply use variables in your `nic` module and then at the interface level you can pass the outputs from `vnet` module as an attribute to your `nic` module.

Refer to the below code.

```
# main.tf or MODULE INTERFACES

## Default variables ##
variable "resource_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "(optional) resource group name in which resources will created"
  default     = "stack-over-flow-query"
}
variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "(optional) location where resources would be created."
  default     = "east us 2"
}

################################

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}
module "ib151w-vnet" {
  source = "./modules/vnet"

  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  vnet_name           = "ib151w-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  subnet_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}
module "ib151w-nic" {
  source = "./modules/nic"

  name                = "${module.ib151w-vnet.vnet_name}-nic-test-123"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  subnet_id           = module.ib151w-vnet.subnet_id
  ip_configuration    = "stackoverflow"
}

## NIC Module 
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = var.ip_configuration
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = var.private_ip_address_allocation
  }
}
## Required variable definitions with defaults(best practice installation in your situation)
```

Using the same outputs as yours in the `vnet` module.

```
output "vnet_name" {
  value = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
}
output "subnet_id" {
  value = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
}
```

**Note:** `"${}"`aka interpolation is not required when using terraform referencing without variables or any unknown value to terraform.

There can be a lot more ways to have a module like this but I would suggest at least a few things to try and do hands-on.

- Use looping in your module to make multiple resources with one interface call [ only when necessary and make sense ]

  - https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/for-each

> Warning: extra looping can increase complexity.

- Use conditions to control your module behavior.

  - https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/conditionals
- And the most important when to use a module.

  - https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop#when-to-write-a-module

I hope this helps and as I have stated this only answers your query, not some best practices or best `vnet-nic` module.

Comment: @ITYD Added the code in the GitHub repo also just in case if  its not clear here :
https://github.com/ishuar/stackoverflow-terraform/tree/main/azure/how_to_get_value_from_modules_in_another_module